# What kind of rights are needed to generate Strong name?

Tags: c#, authentication

sn -k TestKey.snk

is giving me "Failed to create TestKey.snk -- Access is denied."

What kind of rights do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does testkey.snk already exist? Do you have write access to the directory?

Comment: I did not have write access to the directory.